# Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No primary server is available in cluster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, mongoid

I am getting the following error when deploying to production environment (via gitlab):

```
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No primary server is available in cluster: 
#<Cluster topology=
   ReplicaSetNoPrimary[url1:27017,url2:27017,url3:27017,url4:27017,url5:27017,name=mobile01] 
   servers=[
     #<Server address=url1:27017 UNKNOWN>,
     #<Server address=url2:27017 UNKNOWN>,
     #<Server address=url3:27017 UNKNOWN>,
     #<Server address=url4:27017 UNKNOWN>,
     #<Server address=url5:27017 UNKNOWN>]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015
```

I have been trying to reproduce the error locally in a rails console, here is the configuration I have:

```
ap Mongoid.client(:default).instance_values
{
  "srv_records" => nil,
    "options" => {
        "database" => "mydb",
        "auth_source" => "admin",
        "retry_reads" => true,
        "retry_writes" => true,
        "user" => "rp_projects",
        "password" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ssl" => true,
        "replica_set" => "mobile01",
        "connect" => :replica_set,
        "platform" => "mongoid-7.0.5"
   },
   "database" => #<Mongo::Database:0x70156564542240 name=mydb>,
   "cluster" => #<Mongo::Cluster:0x70156564540720 servers=[] 
                   topology=
                   ReplicaSetNoPrimary[url1:27017,url2:27017,url3:27017,url4:27017,url5:27017,
                   name=mobile01]>
}
```

The server is running in a docker image. Am I missing something in the configuration? What should I look for here?

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify you are able to connect to the nodes using the MongoDB shell (`mongo` binary). Most likely you do not have connectivity.
2. Set log level to debug (https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-configuration/#logging) which will tell you what the driver is doing as it is attempting to connect to the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error from docker. This solution will be helpful who is using ruby on rails, mongodb and docker. Here is my config on docker-compose.yml

```
mongodb:
image: mongo:latest
container_name: mongodb
restart: always
ports:
  - "27017:27017"
environment:
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
  MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
  - mongodb_data:/data/db
```

On the mongoid.yml file on the host section I was localhost:27017. But I should write docker service name mongodb.

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: tutorials_development
      hosts:
        - mongodb
```

Answer (score -2):

I had this error:

```
rake aborted!
Mongo::Error::NoServerAvailable: No primary server is available in cluster: #<Cluster topology=Unknown[localhost:27017] servers=[#<Server address=localhost:27017 UNKNOWN>]> with timeout=30, LT=0.015

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

was able to fix it by adding `platform: linux/arm64/v8` to the mongo section in the docker-compose.yml file
if you run this and get:
`Error response from daemon: image with reference mongo:3.7 was found but does not match the specified platform: wanted linux/arm64/v8, actual: linux/amd64`

That means your machine already has an image with the tag `mongo:3.7` but it is for the platform linux/amd64 and not arm64 so it can’t download the same tag. To fix that error, we can delete the image by running:
`docker rmi mongo:3.7` then trying again

side note:
I'm using a Macbook 2021 M1 chip, MacOS Ventura 13.1

Comment: While this is a valid error when building a docker image in newer M1/M2 chips. It is not related to the question.